# October Date PHP DST Syntax

Tags: php, dst

Am trying to fix a PHP script I purchased a while back and think that
the problem lies with calculating Daylight Savings as the problem seems
to occur when dates are included in October. It uses a calender and
it seems to have issues at the moment in October.

I did a search and found a question and reply on this site regarding the
way one day was added to the timestamp to cater for DST. However in that 
instance + 24*60*60 was the method used and in my case +86400 is used - 
although both arrive at the same figure.

Here is the code that I think is the problem:

```
    $day_increase=(strtotime($mysql_checkin_date)+86400);
    $mysql_checkin_date = date('Y-m-d',$day_increase);
```

I think I should change it to '+1 day' instead of the +86400 - does this sound correct?

Whenever I try I seem to get syntax errors so am obviously not correctly structuring it anyway -
here's
one way that I tried:

```
    $day_increase=(strtotime($mysql_checkin_date) '+1 day');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: What does `$mysql_checkin_date` contain?

Comment: You will have the same problem within this year no matter how you do it: +1day, or 86400 (what is one day again). Btw why that is troubling you? If you tell us why, maybe we can came up with some tweak?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply - now sorted with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use [*relative format*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you need to pass the full string:

```
$day_increase = strtotime($mysql_checkin_date . ' +1 day');
```

**Assumption:** `$mysql_checkin_date` is in MySQL date format, i.e. `2013-09-09`.

If `$mysql_checkin_date` is a timestamp, you can pass it as the second parameter:

```
$day_increase = strtotime('+1 day', $mysql_checkin_date);
```

Alternatively, you may want to look into the more robust [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: Many thanks!!! The first one worked and resolved the problems with booking dates between October & November. Also fixed a slow search problem caused by this issue - looks like we cracked it!